# Is there an alternative to getBBox for the use element?

Tags: javascript, svg

Doesn't the `use` SVG element have the getBBox method?
If it doesn't have, is there a proper alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<use>` has a getBBox method.

The interface for use is [defined here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGUseElement) and it implements SVGTransformable. If you click on the link you'll find that SVGTransformable is a subclass of [SVGLocatable](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) and that interface has getBBox.

Comment: I've been trying to use this element in Iceweasel, but I get a "not a function" error.